# Connecting to SalesForce bulk API using C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am trying to connect to the SalesForce.com bulk API so I can do mass uploads of data from my application.  I have read through the [PDF documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynchpre/api_bulk.pdf) which emphasizes using CURL to make the POST requests.  In keeping with the instructions, I have created a text file in XML format which is used for logging into the server.

Login.txt contents below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
     <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <n1:username>my username</n1:username>
         <n1:password>my password</n1:password>
     </n1:login>
     </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Here is what I'm trying to do in my code to make the login request:

```
XmlDocument XMLResponse = null;

HttpWebRequest httpRequest;

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;

Stream requestStream = null;
Stream responseStream = null;

XmlTextReader xmlReader;

httpRequest = HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/20.0");

try
{
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: login");
            requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

            if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

                xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);

                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.Load(xmlReader);

                XMLResponse = xmldoc;
                xmlReader.Close();
            }

            httpResponse.Close();
}
```

When this code executes I always get a 500 error.  Does anyone have any experience in doing what I am attempting to do?  Could you please provide me with some suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know this is for the older Bulk Api 1.0, but if you want to use the Bulk Api 2.0 I recently added support to Reinforce: https://github.com/deesejohn/Reinforce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the login part, just download and import the partner WSDL and use the generated web service client. Otherwise, you'll want to update your code to read the response when it gets a 500 status code (the SOAP spec requires fault messages to use a 500 status code), the response body will give you more clues to the problem. I'd expect in this case you're getting an identity confirmation error, and you'll need to provide your api security token in addition to your password in the login request.

Comment: How can I read the response?  As soon as .GetResponse() is called it sends me down to my catch block with the generic 500 exception, which has no InnerException.

Comment: WebException includes a Response property which you can use to access the response in the exception case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Now when I examine the response I get the following fault message: "The SOAP request must use SOAP 1.1, did not recieve a SOAP 1.1 Envelope as the document root".  I'm not really experienced in using SOAP, so would you happen to see anything in the code I posted above that would account for this issue?

Comment: Again, i would recommend you import the WSDL and use the generated code, rather than building it by hand.

Comment: but won't I be facing the same issue when I go to make the other REST API calls like creating a job or a batch?

Comment: possibly. Have you checked that bytes actually contains the contents of the file you expect it to ?

Comment: i ended up taking your advice and doing the login through the import WSDL and doing the rest of my calls via the Bulk API.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Generate the XML file to salesforce login

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <login xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password + token</password>
    </login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

use the following c# code for login to salesforce

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(str);
                string uri = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/21.0";
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "login");
                req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
                req.Accept = "text/xml";
                req.Method = "POST";
                stm = req.GetRequestStream();
                doc.Save(stm);
                stm.Close();
                WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                stm = resp.GetResponseStream();
                XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
                doc1.Load(stm);
```