# XML Parsing Error - Salesforce Bulk API using C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, salesforce

I'm attempting to [Create a Job](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_CSH.htm#asynch_api_quickstart_create_job.htm) and [Add a Batch](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_CSH.htm#asynch_api_quickstart_add_batch.htm) using the Salesforce Bulk API, but I receive an `XML Parsing Error` back from Salesforce.

As advised in the [Connecting to SalesForce bulk API using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326598/connecting-to-salesforce-bulk-api-using-c-sharp) question, I'm using the partner WSDL to perform the login; that and the Create Job call are working. (Before I had attempted to perform the login by POSTing XML as the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_CSH.htm#asynch_api_quickstart_login.htm) had mentioned; I couldn't get that to work, either.)

Unfortunately, I'm a bit rusty with C#, but here is the code I'm working with.

```
...
using SalesforceTest.sforce;
...

namespace SalesforceTest
{
    public partial class InvokeBulkAPI : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        public string SalesforceLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            SforceService binding = new SforceService();
            binding.Timeout = 60000;

            try
            {
                LoginResult lr = binding.login(username, password);
                binding.Url = lr.serverUrl;

                return lr.sessionId;
            }
            catch (SoapException e) { return e.Message; }
        }

        public string CreateJob(string sfSessionId, string sfOperation, string sfObjectName)
        {
            string str = "";
            string reqURL = "";

            byte[] bytes;

            XmlDocument reqDoc;
            XmlDocument respDoc;

            str = ""
                + "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" // added \r\n as recommended by L.B's answer
                + "<jobInfo xmlns=\"http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload\">"
                + "    <operation></operation>" // removed "+sfOperation+"
                + "    <object></object>" // removed "+sfObjectName+"
                + "    <contentType>XML</contentType>" // should be CSV, NOT XML
                + "</jobInfo>"
            ;

            reqURL = "https://cs12-api.salesforce.com/services/async/23.0/job";
            reqDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
            reqDoc.LoadXml(str);

            // added XML modifications
            reqDoc.GetElementsByTagName("operation")[0].InnerText = sfOperation;
            reqDoc.GetElementsByTagName("object")[0].InnerText = sfObjectName;

            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reqDoc.InnerXml);
            respDoc = Post(bytes, reqURL, sfSessionId); // create job

            string JobId = (respDoc != null) ? 
                (respDoc.GetElementsByTagName("id").Count > 0) ?
                    (respDoc.GetElementsByTagName("id")[0].InnerText) :
                    "" :
                ""
            ;

            return JobId;
        }

        public void AddBatch(string sfSessionId, string sfJobId, byte[] fileBytes)
        {
            string reqURL = "https://cs12-api.salesforce.com/services/async/23.0/job/" + sfJobId + "/batch";
            XmlDocument respDoc = Post(fileBytes, reqURL, sfSessionId);
        }

        public XmlDocument Post(byte[] bytes, string reqURL, string sfSessionId)
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(reqURL);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            req.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"; // should be text/csv; when passing a CSV file
            req.Headers.Add("X-SFDC-Session: " + sfSessionId);

            System.IO.Stream strm = req.GetRequestStream();
            strm.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            strm.Close();

            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream respStrm = resp.GetResponseStream();

            XmlDocument respDoc = new XmlDocument();
            respDoc.Load(respStrm);

            return respDoc;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SessionId = SalesforceLogin(this.TextBox1.Text, this.TextBox2.Text);
            string JobId = CreateJob(SessionId, "insert", "Contact");

            if (JobId.Length > 0)
            {
                AddBatch(SessionId, JobId, this.FileUpload1.FileBytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file I'm posting is the same as the [example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_CSH.htm#asynch_api_quickstart_add_batch.htm) in the documentation.

```
FirstName,LastName,Department,Birthdate,Description
Tom,Jones,Marketing,1940-06-07Z,"Self-described as ""the top"" branding guru on the West Coast"
Ian,Dury,R&D,,"World-renowned expert in fuzzy logic design. 
Influential in technology purchases."
```

My question is **why would I receive an XML Parsing Error from Salesforce on Line Number 1, Column 1**?

This is what I receive:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: https://####.salesforce.com/services/async/23.0/job/###/batch/###/request
Line Number 1, Column 1:

FirstName,LastName,Department,Birthdate,Description
^
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all never create an xml with string manipulations. Use an XML parser like XmlDocument or XDocument.

Xml Declaration should be on a seperate line `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>`. you forget `\r\n`

Third, you should set `text/csv` as content type when sending csv

Comment: Excellent advice, thanks! 

I added `\r\n` to the XML Declaration, removed the string manipulations (using `reqDoc.GetElementsByTagName("operation")[0].InnerText = sfOperation;` instead), changed the CreateBatch XML to use `CSV` as the contentType, and changed the AddBatch Post method call to pass `text/csv`. With those modifications, everything worked, and the batch was successfully added.

It's been so long since I've worked with this stuff..

Answer (score 2):

The example uses curl to send csv. You are sending csv to a service expecting xml. Find an example with xml data or try invoking with same params as they use for curl.